# hidden value to call title from vb.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net

am trying to call a hidden field and call the title as "apple" to my chart in javascript,

my code behind is :

```
   Dim title As String
            If RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value = 1 Then
                title = "apple"
            End If
```

i have also made a hidden field so i can call it in the javascript highcharts.

```
   hidden10.Value
```

my problem is in the code behind how am i going to set the hidden value to "apple" so i can call hidden10 in javascript?

Comment: Welcome to the messed-up world of server vs. client code in .NET

Comment: lol, any ideas. its so confusing,

Comment: Its still somewhat unclear what you are trying to do. Please understand that "codebehind" executes on the server and determine how the page is sent to the client. JavaScript is executed on the client and can make changes on the page afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

try going

```
hidden10.Value = title
```

after assigning it to "apple" then retrieving the value from javascript.

Comment: yeah got it, would you no how i will call it in javascript, because before i used json... now am just using hidden value

Comment: assign an id to the hidden value when it's declared, then just use docment.getElementById   see this link for more details on what you're trying to do... http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-get-hidden-field-value-in-javascript/